# Error from server: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.9.84.149:10250: getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster with three nodes: `10.9.84.149`,`10.9.105.90` and `10.9.84.149`. When my application tries to execute the command inside some pod:

```
kuebctl exec -it <podName>
```

it sometimes gets an error:

```
Error from server: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.9.84.149:10250: getsockopt: connection refused
```

As far as I could see everything was fine with the cluster: all kube-system services and pods were running well. Besides, it didn't appear regularly.

Can anybody help me on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error as this below

`Error from server: Get https://192.168.100.102:10250/containerLogs/default/kubia-n8nv9/kubia: dial tcp 192.168.100.102:10250: connect: no route to host`

**DISABLING THE FIREWALL WAS MY FIX ON ALL NODES**

I figured out my worker nodes firewall was not disabled. I did instruction below to fix my problem

````
systemctl disable firewalld && systemctl stop firewalld
-Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1...
-Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/firewalld.service.```
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your kubelet process not running, or keep restarting.

```
 ss -tnpl |grep 10250
LISTEN     0      128         :::10250                   :::*                   users:(("kubelet",pid=1102,fd=21))
```

1. check kubelet process is running.
2. if its running see when its started.
3. look at /var/log/message file for any issue with node.
4. Make sure you don't have the firewall blocking the traffic

Comment: I was wrong about the status of kubelet before.Actually,it was true that my kubelet restarted every 5 minutes.I had resolved the problem,thank you.