# kubernetes kubectl exec forbidden

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I did a basic kubernetes installation, and added hello-world pod. When I try to kubectl exec, I get below error.

```
kubectl logs hello-world-pod1

Error from server (Forbidden): pods "hello-world-pod1" is forbidden: User "system:node:kubnode1" cannot get resource "pods/log" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

kubectl exec -it hello-world-pod1 -- /bin/sh

Error from server (Forbidden): pods "hello-world-pod1" is forbidden: User "system:node:kw1" cannot create resource "pods/exec" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

There is not any special installation, just basic instructions, and could not access shell of a basic pod, i researched internet but could not find any solution or source of error.

Comment: You are using kubeconfig of the kubelet . Try running with right kubeconfig.

Comment: This sounds like a Kubernetes RBAC issue, and you'd have to contact your cluster administrator.

Comment: its standart install, where i find right kubeconfig

Answer (score 0):

This is an access issue and it has nothing to do with the pod itself, you need to use the credentials which has access.
You can use `kubectl auth can-i` command to check if you have access.

You will get error if pod does not have the shell that you try to exec into but it is not "User "system:node:kw1" cannot create" error.

Comment: thanks for directing to a path i at least could know where to check. I researched and found this 

kubectl auth can-i '*' '*' command to check if i have all rights
Command returned "yes" though

its a basic kubernetes install and i did all installation as said in document, do i have some missing setting something in that case, when i execute in master node, it says you got all rights, but exec says still forbidden :)

I was trying execute in node1, because i saw pod lives there. When i try to access shell of hello-world in master node, it gives below:

Comment: root@kuberM1 /root: kubectl auth can-i '*' '*'
yes
root@kuberM1 /root: kubectl exec -it hello-world-pod1 -- /bin/sh
Error from server: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.0.2.46:10250: connect: no route to host
root@kuberM1 /root:

Comment: According to that error, did you try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140813/error-from-server-error-dialing-backend-dial-tcp-10-9-84-14910250-getsockopt)?

Answer (score 0):

Due to following error that appears in your case:

```
Error from server: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.0.2.46:10250: connect: no route to host
```

I would suggest disabling the firewall on all nodes.
To fix the problem for not disabled worker nodes firewall run:

````yaml
systemctl disable firewalld && systemctl stop firewalld
-Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1...
-Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/firewalld.service.```
````

See also references:

- [This similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140813/error-from-server-error-dialing-backend-dial-tcp-10-9-84-14910250-getsockopt)
- [Documentation connected to non-public IP used for containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/)